# Error in loading database data to tableview

Tags: database, javafx, tableview

I'm trying load my database data which I created using Microsoft Access to table view in NetBeans JavaFX program but it has an error. So if there is anyone here who can help out with this.

TableViewController.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;



/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class TableViewController  implements Initializable{


    @FXML
TableView<InvoiceEntry> tblViewer;
@FXML
TableColumn colID;
@FXML
TableColumn colName;
@FXML
TableColumn colAuthor;
@FXML
TableColumn colPublisher;
@FXML
TableColumn colPrice;
@FXML
Button cmdTest;
public Statement st;




    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, Integer>("id"));
                colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("name"));
                colAuthor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("author"));
                colPublisher.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, String>("publisher"));
                colPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<InvoiceEntry, Integer>("price"));
                //tblViewer.getItems().setAll(getAllBookInfo());
                tblViewer.getItems().setAll(getAllBookInfo());


    }

    public class InvoiceEntry {
     private final SimpleIntegerProperty bookId ;
    private final SimpleStringProperty bookName; 
    private final SimpleStringProperty Bookauthor; 
    private final SimpleStringProperty Bookpublisher; 
    public SimpleStringProperty Bookprice;    
    public InvoiceEntry(Integer id, String name, String auth, String pub){
      this.bookId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.bookName = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.Bookauthor = new SimpleStringProperty(auth);  
      this.Bookpublisher = new SimpleStringProperty(pub);

    }
    public int invoiceId;

    public Integer getBookId() {
        return bookId.get();
    }
    public void setBookId(Integer id){
          bookId.set(id);      
      }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName.get();
    }
    public void setBookName(String name){
          bookName.set(name);      
      }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Bookauthor.get();
    }
    public void setAuthor(String auth){
          Bookauthor.set(auth);      
      }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return Bookpublisher.get();
    }
    public void setPublisher(String pub){
          Bookpublisher.set(pub);      
      }

    }

    public List<String> getAllBookInfo(){

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\GUI\\Library.accdb","","");
            System.out.println("connected...");
            st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            String recordQuery = ("Select * from BookDB");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(recordQuery);
            while(rs.next()){
                Integer id = rs.getInt("bid");
                String name = rs.getString("bname");
                String auth = rs.getString("author");
                String pub = rs.getString("publisher");
                //myList.add(new InvoiceEntry(id, name, auth, pub));
                myList.add(new InvoiceEntry(id, name, auth, pub));




            }
        } 

        catch (Exception ex) 

        {

        }
        return myList;

}
}
```

Error Message:

```
D:\GUI\JavaFXApplication24\src\javafxapplication24\TableViewController.java:61: error: no suitable method found for setAll(List<String>)
                tblViewer.getItems().setAll(getAllBookInfo());
    method ObservableList.setAll(TableViewController.InvoiceEntry...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; List<String> cannot be converted to TableViewController.InvoiceEntry)
    method ObservableList.setAll(Collection<? extends TableViewController.InvoiceEntry>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; List<String> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends TableViewController.InvoiceEntry>)
D:\GUI\JavaFXApplication24\src\javafxapplication24\TableViewController.java:130: error: no suitable method found for add(TableViewController.InvoiceEntry)
                myList.add(new InvoiceEntry(id, name, auth, pub));
    method Collection.add(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; TableViewController.InvoiceEntry cannot be converted to String)
    method List.add(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; TableViewController.InvoiceEntry cannot be converted to String)
Note: D:\GUI\JavaFXApplication24\src\javafxapplication24\TableViewController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
D:\GUI\JavaFXApplication24\nbproject\build-impl.xml:931: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\GUI\JavaFXApplication24\nbproject\build-impl.xml:271: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Check the type parameters in the `getAllBookInfo` method... `String` != `InvoiceEntry`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>()` which have to contain `String` but you are trying to add `InvoiceEntry` so you get the compile error at
`myList.add(new InvoiceEntry(id, name, auth, pub));` since it cannot be converted to String.

I don't know what IDE are you using but I'm sure abut that IntelliJ, Eclipse and Netbeans notify you where and why do you have compile error.